# Issue with ggplot2, geom_bar, and position="dodge": stacked has correct y values, dodged does not

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I'm having quite the time understanding `geom_bar()` and `position="dodge"`. I was trying to make some bar graphs illustrating two groups. Originally the data was from two separate data frames. Per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8901330/multiple-histograms-with-ggplot2-position), I put my data in long format. My example:

```
test <- data.frame(names=rep(c("A","B","C"), 5), values=1:15)
test2 <- data.frame(names=c("A","B","C"), values=5:7)

df <- data.frame(names=c(paste(test$names), paste(test2$names)), num=c(rep(1, 
nrow(test)), rep(2, nrow(test2))), values=c(test$values, test2$values))
```

I use that example as it's similar to the spend vs. budget example. Spending has many rows per `names` factor level whereas the budget only has one (one budget amount per category).

For a stacked bar plot, this works great:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=factor(names), y=values, fill=factor(num))) +
geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

[image: stacked plot]

In particular, note the y value maxes. They are the sums of the data from `test` with the values of `test2` shown on blue on top.

Based on other questions I've read, I simply need to add `position="dodge"` to make it a side-by-side plot vs. a stacked one:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=factor(names), y=values, fill=factor(num))) + 
geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge")
```

[image: dodged]

It looks great, but note the new max y values. It seems like it's just taking the max y value from each names factor level from `test` for the y value. It's no longer summing them.

Per some other questions (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3773969/ggplot-position-dodge-question) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11005782/ggplot2-geom-bar-position-dodge-does-not-dodge), I also tried adding the `group=` option without success (produces the same dodged plot as above):

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=factor(names), y=values, fill=factor(num), group=factor(num))) +
geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge")
```

I don't understand why the stacked works great and the dodged doesn't just put them side by side instead of on top.

---

**ETA:** I found a [recent question](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/ggplot2/tdiL-Gq3ThQ) about this on the ggplot google group with the suggestion to add `alpha=0.5` to see what's going on. It isn't that ggplot is taking the max value from each grouping; it's actually over-plotting bars on top of one another for each value.

It seems that when using `position="dodge"`, ggplot expects only one y per x. I contacted Winston Chang, a ggplot developer about this to confirm as well as to inquire if this can be changed as I don't see an advantage.

It seems that `stat="identity"` should tell ggplot to tally the `y=val` passed inside `aes()` instead of individual counts which happens without `stat="identity"` and when passing no y value.

For now, the workaround seems to be (for the original df above) to aggregate so there's only one y per x:

```
df2 <- aggregate(df$values, by=list(df$names, df$num), FUN=sum)
p <- ggplot(df2, aes(x=Group.1, y=x, fill=factor(Group.2)))
p <- p + geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge")
p
```

[image: correct]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think the problem is that you want to stack *within* values of the `num` group, and dodge *between* values of `num`.
It might help to look at what happens when you add an outline to the bars.

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(
  id     = 1:18,
  names  = rep(LETTERS[1:3], 6),
  num    = c(rep(1, 15), rep(2, 3)),
  values = sample(1:10, 18, replace=TRUE)
)
```

By default, there are a lot of bars stacked - you just don't see that they're separate unless you have an outline:

```
# Stacked bars
ggplot(df, aes(x=factor(names), y=values, fill=factor(num))) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", colour="black")
```

[image: Stacked bars]

If you dodge, you get bars that are dodged between values of `num`, but there may be multiple bars within each value of `num`:

```
# Dodged on 'num', but some overplotted bars
ggplot(df, aes(x=factor(names), y=values, fill=factor(num))) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", colour="black", position="dodge", alpha=0.1)
```

[image: Dodged on num]

If you also add `id` as a grouping var, it'll dodge all of them:

```
# Dodging with unique 'id' as the grouping var
ggplot(df, aes(x=factor(names), y=values, fill=factor(num), group=factor(id))) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", colour="black", position="dodge", alpha=0.1)
```

[image: Dodge all bars]

I think what you want is to both dodge and stack, but you can't do both.
So the best thing is to summarize the data yourself.

```
library(plyr)
df2 <- ddply(df, c("names", "num"), summarise, values = sum(values))

ggplot(df2, aes(x=factor(names), y=values, fill=factor(num))) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", colour="black", position="dodge")
```

[image: Summarized beforehand]

Comment: Got it. It was quite helpful for you to point out that I'm actually asking for both dodging and stacking. One quibble: when not using `stat="identity"` (so basically making a histogram), isn't ggplot "stacking" individual counts while dodging between some other characteristic? Even so, I'm okay with the answer that it's just how it works at the moment. I thought I was doing something wrong in my code!

Comment: `geom_bar` can be a little confusing because it's used for two different purposes: Sometimes it's used to plot y values that you provide, and sometimes it counts up the number of cases in each and uses that count as the y value (with `stat="bin"`). The latter behavior is the default (you can see it with `ggplot(df, aes(x=factor(names), fill=factor(num))) + geom_bar(colour="black")` ). In this case, the "stacking" is not quite the same -- it's a summary _stat_, whereas the usual stacking is a _position adjustment_. These things happen at different stages of the ggplot pipeline.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Aggregating is not a big deal and now I know I need to, which is a big step from just being confused :)